# Remove therubyracer or fix timeout when pushing to Heroku

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, heroku, rubygems

We've been wanting to upgrade our app to **Ruby** `2.1.5`. We use **Heroku** as our deployment service and **Rails** `4.0.13`. When we push into **Heroku**, we're getting the following error:

```
Could not find libv8-3.3.10 in any of the sources
 !
 !     Failed to install gems via Bundler.
 !

 !     Push rejected, failed to compile Ruby app
```

This is because we're using the **therubyracer** gem, in its `0.10.2` version. That version depends on **libv8** version `3.3.10`, which apparently isn't available for **Ruby** `2.1` (because when using **Ruby** `2.0`, we don't get this issue). We could upgrade to the latest **therubyracer** version, `0.12.1`, but this gives us:

```
Timed out compiling Ruby app (15 minutes)
```

almost all the time whenever we push. Also, this gem is not recommended for Heroku ([therubyracer in Heroku](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/rails-asset-pipeline#therubyracer)). Which of course lead us to wanting to remove it.

However, we're also using **less-rails** for our project. This gem depends on **therubyracer** https://github.com/metaskills/less-rails#installing). This makes it difficult for us to remove **therubyracer**. One way to solve this is to stop using **less** and begin using **sass**, but we want to avoid that as much as possible.

Is there any way to remove **therubyracer** and still use **less-rails**? If not possible, can we avoid the timeouts when pushing?